# how do I extract a specific substring from a string in c# using a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, json, string-formatting

I am trying to extract just the route number from a response I get from a web server. The response looks like this;

[{"Description":"METRO Blue Line","ProviderID":"8","Route":"901"},{"Description":"METRO Green Line","ProviderID":"8","Route":"902"},

All I need is to get the route numbers so I can populate a combobox with them. I am trying to use a loop as there are quite a few. My current solution gets the first route number, but then for some reason I only get the provider number after that.This is what I have so far.

```
        //get bus routes and popluate the busRoutecmb
        restClient.endPoint = routeUrl + formatLine;
        string response = restClient.request();

        //show me what was returned for debug puposes
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(response);

        //sort through data and put relevent item in a list
        List<string> responseItems = new List<string>();
        //splitting into routes
        string[] splitByRoute = response.Split('}');

        //extracting route number from elements in splitByRoute
        List<string> extractedRouteNums = new List<string>();

        foreach (string thing in splitByRoute)
        {
            //splitting each bus route up by piece of information
            string[] splitByWord = thing.Split(',');
            //getting rid of everything but the route number
            int length = splitByWord.Length;
            int count = 2;
            while (count <= length)
            {
                string[] word = splitByWord[count].Split(':');
                string routeNum = word[1].Trim('"');
                count += 3;
                extractedRouteNums.Add(routeNum);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(count);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(routeNum);

            }

        }

        //add repsonse to busRoutecmb
        busRoutecmb.DataSource = extractedRouteNums;

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use JSON.NET to deserialize the JSON string? You don't need to parse it using string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

What your getting back is basically a JSON string which is just an array of name value pairs or a Dictionary List.

```
  [{
        "Description": "METRO Blue Line",
        "ProviderID": "8",
        "Route": "901"
    },
    {
        "Description": "METRO Green Line",
        "ProviderID": "8",
        "Route": "902"
    }]
```

You can deserialize that string into a List in several ways one is to use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer or JSON.NET. Once in a List you can query that list and return just the route key,Value pair.

```
    var data = "[{ Description:\"METROBlueLine\",ProviderID:\"8\",Route:\"901\"},{Description:\"METRO Green Line\",ProviderID:\"8\",Route:\"902\"}]";

                var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                var mylist = ser.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(data);
    //or JSON.net
                var mylist = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                var routes = mylist.SelectMany(a => a).Where(c => c.Key == "Route").ToList();
                foreach (var route in routes)
                    Console.Write(route);

    output
    [Route, 901][Route, 902]
```

If you really only want the values then

```
var routesonly = routes.Select(r => r.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is obsolete. Its [own documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) starts with `Json.NET should be used for serialization and deserialization.`

Comment: Yes of course but I did not want to make any assumptions as to what limitations OP had

Answer (score 0):

Gratzy is right about this being JSON, but I would propose you use JSON.NET to deserialize it.

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(response);
var routeNumbers = items.Select(i => i.Value<string>("Route")).ToList();
```

You could also use http://json2csharp.com/ to produce a strongly-typed model, and deserialize to that model type if you prefer.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
}

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(response);
var routeNumbers = items.Select(i => i.Route).ToList();
```